# Open connection over peering VPC

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-web-services

I'm on aws and have 3 vpc connected in a so called "flying V" model https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/vpc/latest/peering/peering-configurations-full-access.html#one-to-two-vpcs-full-access, 1 admin vpc (10.100.0.0/16) linked to 1 slave vpc (10.110.0.0/16) and 1 production vpc (10.120.0.0/16). very similar to https://www.whaletech.co/2014/10/02/reference-vpc-architecture.html

I need to use the admin vpc as a centralized access point and from there connect to the other two vpc.

I set up the peering connection from admin->slave and from admin->production and also set up the routes table to permit traffic trough vpc.

Now I can connect with putty on the public-layer admin nat-ec2 and from here I can:

```
ssh ec2-user@10.100.10.123 //private service layer
```

and connect to the admin-ec2 inside the service layer.

<del>How can I connect from admin vpc to a slave-ec2 inside the slave vpc?</del>
<del>ssh ec2-user@10.110.10.321 //this dont work</del>

[edit]

Here (inside the admin private layer server) I'm able to ping to another server, in another vpc private layer. What command line do I need to fire to switch to that server??

Comment: I found that my route tables were not correctly set up. Now when I try to log to an instance on another vpc a have a "Permission denied: (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mix)" error

Comment: I found now that I can ping to the server in the other vpc, so now the question is, how can I access the command line of that server?

Comment: To solve my problem I found usefull this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345106/vpc-peering-issues-between-bastion-and-app-server-ec2